# Прогресс загрузки web-страницы

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, node.js, http

Представим что у нас сайт (SPA), все страницы грузятся аяксом, мы к примеру юзаем history api.
Возможно ли, каким-то образом, показывать юзеру прогресс загрузки страницы? Именно не какую-то анимацию, а реальные данные. Пример того что имею ввиду - красная полоса загрузки, вверху, на youtube.com. Я не думаю что там реальный прогресс, но все же, хочется услышать идеи несмотря на то - насколько тупая эта идея.
Это все, при учете что на бэкенде nodejs или php.
Как я делал (но получилось просто фэйкопрогрессбар, но выглядело красиво):

1. Когда юзер кликает на ссылку, прогрессбар начинает наполняться, скорость анимации на этом этапе равна макс. врем. ожидания на сервере в соответствии с шириной самого прогрессбара.
2. Если ответ пришел, то быстро, плавно, наполняем прогрессбар до конца (300ms например).
3. Если нет ответа то ждем ошибку о истечении time-out и прячем прогресс.

Все это завязано на времени, как упомянул выше - выглядит неплохо, ну так же как это сделано на ютубе. Но вот интересно, можно ли именно реальные данные показывать, вплоть до размера загружаемой страницы и скорости загрузки прям на этом прогрессбаре.

Comment: Вы всё правильно делаете, реальности не нужно, это не игра и там не гигабайты шейдеров грузятся. Прогрессбар на сайтах нужен для того, чтобы показать юзеру что что-то происходит и сайт не повис. Youtube делает так же. И популярный плагин http://ricostacruz.com/nprogress/ делает так же.

Comment: JavaScript начнёт выполняться после загрузки части содержимого. Чтобы контролировать процесс загрузки можно большую часть dom-дерева формировать динамически на стороне клиента. Контроллируя процесс готовности создаваемых элементов.

Получается, если javascript отключен и javascript-загрузчик не работает, то страница отобразится почти пустой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно получать общий размер загружаемого файла и сколько загружено на данный момент.

В кратце вот так:

```
var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

if ('onprogress' in xhr) {
    progressBar.parent().show();
    loadingPanel.hide();

    var last = 0, max = 100 / len;
    xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = Math.min((evt.loaded / evt.total) * max, max);

            if (last < percentComplete) {
                progressWidth += percentComplete - last;
                last = percentComplete;
                progressBar.width(progressWidth + '%');
            }
        }
    }, false);
}
```

Когда-то давно на похожую тему писал статью на хабре: [возможно поможет](http://habrahabr.ru/post/193484/)

Answer (score 1):

Я использую для отбражения процесса загрузки каринки, т.к. она самые тяжелые на сайте, т.е. мы выбираем все картинки на сайта

```
document.querySelector('*') if img
```

далее использую одну из библиотек проверки предзагрузки картинок, например вот эту https://github.com/CreateJS/PreloadJS
А дальше просто выводим процент загрузки, получаются реальные данные загрузки.